# A word to describe thing or activity that is usually happens with other people

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

For example:

- The movie contains violent scenes, (that usually can be seen in) the Tarantino movies.
- He barely know us, but gave us a warm welcome, (that's usually given by) close friends.

What word can be used instead of phrases in the brackets?

**Update**

I've found the word *inherent* which seems to have meaning close to what I'm looking for. Correct me if I'm wrong.

> There are liability issues inherent in undercover journalism.

Comment: Not much of a language expert I am, and it's not a single word either, but I think "typical of" can replace both your phrases.

Comment: You mean *-esque*? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-esque  
In the manner of; resembling: *Lincolnesque*.

Comment: close-friendesque?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one particularly good word for these phrases, nor do I think you should try to use only one word. These would be better expressed in the following ways (among others):

The movie contains violent scenes, the type often seen in Tarantino movies.

He barely knows us, but gave us a warm welcome, the kind he usually reserves for close friends.